# How to implement division using Garbled Circuit

Tags: garbled-circuits, arithmetic

Implementing Addition, Subtraction and even N-bit Multiplication can be done fairly quickly and intuitively using garbled circuit, since no looping, control unit nor state machine is needed. One just has to give every wire two random labels and it's done.

However, I am unsure about how to implement N-bit **division**. Of course, one can build a gigantic truth table and figure out the logic expression, but this way the circuit size would be enormous and  it's neither reusable nor practical.

I have the following 32-bit division diagram, which is a very simple conceptual design:

[image]
*Diagram is from [here](http://bwrcs.eecs.berkeley.edu/Classes/icdesign/ee141_s04/Project/Divider%20Background.pdf), p8*

So it contains a **control unit**, which I assume contains a clock.

So my question takes three forms:

1. How to implement a N-bit division garbled circuit?
2. How to implement a control unit in GC?
3. How does GC work with clock?

Comment: GC circuits are straight lined - no flip flops.  Just unroll the algorithm into a straight line set of logic gates.